# How to get country specific result (only for UK) in HERE MAP iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

> [HEREDeveloperSupport](http://HEREDeveloperSupport)

Is there any method for AutoSuggestionRequest to get country specific result?

I am using the Native IOS SDK premium edition version 3.15,i need to show UK results only.

I am following the below code

```
 let autoSuggestionRequest = NMAPlaces.sharedInstance()!.createAutoSuggestionRequest(location:geo,
            partialTerm:text, resultType:getResultType())

        autoSuggestionRequest?.languagePreference = languageLabel.text
```

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport can i get any responce from your side.

Comment: @here-api @ HEREDeveloperSupport

i am really surprise, you dose not provide the feature country search restriction, can you guys confirm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my R&D (posting date) and discuss with the HERE MAP support team on slack, there is no any method to find the Specific country address search result for example show UK results only. ( 3.x Premium SDK)

Now, I have created custom auto search bar using the POST API and it's working fine but it's showing the search address in your current location.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find this option in the 3.x Premium SDK (though I might also be missing it). As a workaround you can directly call the Autosuggest endpoint of the [Search & Geocoding API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html). Using the "in" parameter and country code you can limit your results to a specific country.

Alternatively you can filter the results based on their country afterwards, though I understand that is less than convenient.